# Compact Space $A^Z\times A^Z\times Z$?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let A be some finite Alphabet.

Them of course $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is Compact By Tychonoff.

But do we also have that
$A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{Z}$
is Compact?

I guess Not...

Comment: Well, does the cover $A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \{0\}, A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \{1\}, A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \{-1\}, \ldots$ have a finite subcover?

Comment: No, it hasn't. But can we endow $A^{Z}\times A^{Z}\times Z$ with some metric in order to make it Compact?

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z}$ is not compact, then we can always use some counterexample cover to give a counterexample cover to $A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times A^{\mathbb{Z}}\times \mathbb{Z}$.  So you need to topologize $\mathbb{Z}$ somehow so that it is compact.

Comment: You can endow any set $X$ with a compact topology. For example, the topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$ is compact, for any set $X$.